# Blender 2.8 Beta (Linux Mint 19.1): No compatible GPUs found - Vega 64 Nitro+

Tags: gpu, drivers, linux, hardware

I can't find any working information, how to fix this, and before I was trying to install some other drivers for my Vega, but i accidentally broke my previous installation.

[image: SS]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You most probably have installed the open source driver stack that comes with Mint.

On any GNU/Linux distribution, Blender only supports the official AMD proprietary drivers for rendering with OpenCL, meaning you will need to install one of the following AMD OpenCL drivers:

- AMDGPU
- AMDGPU-PRO

For Linux Mint, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/9mxafp/how_to_install_the_ubuntu_amdgpu_drivers_from_amd/) might be a good start

There might be another method to just install the OpenCL part of the AMMDGPU-PRO driver, which is described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/install-opencl-for-the-amdgpu-open-source-drivers-on-debian-and-ubuntu), but I don't have the  means to test it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are installing your AMD-Pro drivers you have to type

`./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=pal,legacy,rocm`.

I was facing the same problem for a long time but this solved it.